# python requests module unable to use error message

Tags: python

I did not exactly know how to word it in the title but essentially I have an IP address API, which if an API is valid it gives data, if it isn't it provides an error message ([https://ipapi.co/{args[0]}/json/](https://ipapi.co/%7Bargs%5B0%5D%7D/json/)). The problem with this API is there is no error name when it is successful. So I made an if statement that checks if the API returned an Error:

```py
API = f'https://ipapi.co/{args[0]}/json/'
json_data = requests.get(api).json()

if json_data['error'] == True:
   print(f'There was an error with the API') # something like this.
else:
countryname = json_data['country_name']
countrycode = json_data['country_code']
region = json_data['region']
```

The problem with this is if an error is returned then it will say so, but if there isn't I just get a console error because it is a valid IP and therefore is not returning an error name. Is there anyway I can check to see if there is a name called error? I'm sorry if my wording was off, English is not my first language.

Comment: can you give a example of a "good" url and a "bad" url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get()` method of `dict`. It will return `None`, instead of raising exception, if key was not found:

```py
if json_data.get('error'):
   print(f'There was an error with the API') # something like this.
else:
    countryname = json_data['country_name']
    countrycode = json_data['country_code']
    region = json_data['region']
```